# ASP.NET MVC - how to make ajax helper replace itself?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("PLUS", "VotePlus", "Forums", new {postId = Model.Id}, new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "votePlus",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    },
    new{@id="votePlus"}
)
```

It generates link that says "PLUS". Now, i have a controller action that returns null (I also tried with empty partialView with no result). I want this link to disappear when user clicks on it. How can I do that?

Edit: It appears that this whole thing doesn't want to work. I created span tag and wanted it to replace itself, but this ajax helper keeps redirecting me to controller action. :-/

Comment: Have you referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in your layout?

Comment: You are missing a script or multiple scripts. I don't think `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is the only one you need.

Comment: Yes, thank you guys, i was missing this one. Now it works but i have another problem - i want this link to update span element and hide itself, how can i do that? Is that even possible with ajax helpers?

Comment: you could put a container around it and hide that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach, try using OnSuccess callback of AjaxOptions to call a javascript function to hide the link and update span

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("PLUS", "VotePlus", "Forums", new {postId = Model.Id}, new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = ‘onSuccessProc’
    },
    new{@id="votePlus"}
)

// in your javascript section
function onSuccessProc(respData){
    // code to update span assuming server returns html
    $(‘#id_of_span’).html(respData);
    $(‘# votePlus’).hide();
};
```